# Using regular expressions inside of a hashtable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following hashtable:

```
$lookupTable = @{
    "^XXX"="123";
    "^YYY"="456";
    "cat"="dog"
}
```

I'm performing a bulk find & replace operation in files as such:

```
Foreach-Object {
    $file = $_
    Write-Host "$file"
    (Get-Content -Path $file) | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            $line = $line -replace "$_.Name", "$_.Value"
        }
        $line
    } | Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

You'll notice I have an anchor/caret (`^`) on the first two pairs of the hashtable.  This is because I want to perform a regex on these so they only match if they are at the beginning of the line.  For the third set (`"cat"="dog"`) I want to match anywhere (no regular expressions). Unfortunatley, it seems to be taking the `^` literally and is not finding matches nor doing a regex evaluation.  I tried defining the regex like below and it works for the first two sets (`"XXX"="123"` & `"YYY"="456"`), but it won't work for the third set (`"cat"="dog"`) as I need to find `cat` anywhere in the file, not just at the beginning of the line:

```
$line = $line -replace "^$($_.Name)", "$($_.Value)"
```

How can I accomplish this?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The trick was to remove the quotes (`"`) from `$line = $line -replace "$_.Name", "$_.Value"` so it would actually interpolate the item vs. treating it as a literal string.  So the correct code should be:

`$line = $line -replace $_.Name, $_.Value`

Comment: Your solution is effective (and better than your original attempt), but the explanation isn't correct: `"..."` strings _do_ interpolate (unlike `'..'` strings), it's just that you need to enclose _expressions_ such as property references in `$(...)` - see the linked post.

Comment: Spot on.  I wasn't sure what to search for and as I'm sure you know, learning is like peeling an onion. Thank you for the linked post. I'm studying up on how PowerShell handles `"..."`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Can I suggest you correct your answer so as not to confuse future readers?